# Instantiate parent but acces subclass attributes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, inheritance, android-activity

I have a parent class with several subclass. At one point of my code I need to use the attributes of the subclass but I need to declare it as the parent. How can I do it?

I instantiate it this way:

```
Parent oObj = new SonN();
```

And at some point I need to use an attribute of the child:

```
oObj.sonAttribute = x
```

I do this because I am using fragments. In each fragment oObj will be a different child and I need to access from the main Activity to this object and use an oParent method.

All my fragments inherits from a parent fragment who contains this object:

```
public class FragmentParent extends Fragment {
public Parent oObj;}
```

Comment: You can't do that unless you check for its instance type and typecast it.. you can, obviously, access the parent's attributes.

Comment: polymorphism applies only to methods in java . So it is not possible to access subclass attributes with super class reference .

Answer (score 0):

Create a getter (accessor) method for the attribute in the parent, as one should always do. Override it in the child as needed. Only refer to the attribute through the accessor, as one should nearly always do.